# return a tuple with names in F#

Tags: c#, f#

In C# I can do this:

```
public (bool result, string message) Hello()
{
    ...
    return (true, "ok")
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to do it in F#.

I can do:

```
let Hello () =
    (true, "ok")
```

but then, when I call Hello from C#, I have to get the elements as 'Item1' and 'Item2'.

Is there a way to name the field in the returned tuple?

I tried:

```
let hello () : (result, message ): bool * string =
```

and a few other variations, but I can't make that work.

The type returned is seen as a tuple object, in C#, whereas the pure C# example shown above doesn't seem to be using the tuple type.

I guess you can't name the items in a tuple object, but is there a way to return parameters like in C#?

Comment: not too sure you can, this article may help  http://mustoverride.com/tuples_names/   it points to need an attribute, not sure if that is achievable with F#

Comment: Standard F# tuples are `System.Tuple` under the hood, while the tuple returned from your C# code is the newer `System.ValueTuple`. To create that from F#, you need to prefix your tuple creation with the `struct` keyword. That still doesn't let you name tuple elements in F#, though; that is a C# compiler feature. The options you have in F# are a) destructuring the tuple (see http://teadrivendev.github.io/2016/01/04/pattern_matching_record_fields/) at the site where it's being used, b) returning a record, or c) in F# 4.7 potentially an anonymous record.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev your comment should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Standard F# tuples are `System.Tuple` under the hood (which would be written as `Tuple<bool, string>` in C#), while the tuple returned from your C# code is the newer `System.ValueTuple`. To create that from F#, you need to prefix your tuple creation with the `struct` keyword. That still doesn't let you name tuple elements in F#, though; that is only a C# compiler feature and has no support in the underlying BCL types.

The options you have in F# to use the individual returned values in a similar manner are

- destructuring the tuple (see http://teadrivendev.github.io/2016/01/04/pattern_matching_record_fields/) at the site where it's being used,
- returning a record, or
- in F# 4.7 potentially returning an anonymous record (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/anonymous-records).

Answer (score 1):

F# doesn't support this feature today, but if you want to expose names for C# you can manually use `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TupleElementNamesAttribute`. Note that you need to use `struct` to get F# to use `ValueTuple` instead of `Tuple`, to match C#.

```
let Hello () : 
    [<return: TupleElementNames([| "result"; "message" |])>] struct(bool * string) =
    (true, "ok")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a struct tuple in your F#code, for example

```
let f (struct (x,y)) = x+y
```

You can find the design document here

https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp-4.1/FS-1006-struct-tuples.md

When you want to interop with C#, you should look at this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/tuples

In summary, calling a C# code, you can

```
open TupleInterop

 let struct (newX, newY) = Example.AddOneToXAndY(struct (1, 2))
 // newX is now 2, and newY is now 3
```

Comment: what is the difference with create a custom return type?

Comment: this answer doesn't answer the question, which is how to to access things from C# and how from F# can you set the names.  Not how to access C# from F#